# How to properly configure nginx proxy pass when the endpoint is in a root context?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to figure out how to configure a reverse proxy in nginx when the endpoint is in a root context:

`http://frontend.com/mylink` proxy forwards to `http://10.0.0.2:8000/`

Unfortunately I can't change the context of the application at `http://10.0.0.2:8000`, so I'm trying to figure out a workaround in nginx for this issue. The following configuration usually works fine when there is a context, but doesn't work in the situation above:

```
location /mylink {
    proxy_pass     http://10.0.0.2:8000;
    proxy_redirect http://10.0.0.2:8000 /mylink;
    port_in_redirect off;
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3):

I think if you change it to:

```
location /mylink {
   proxy_pass     http://10.0.0.2:8000/;
   proxy_redirect http://10.0.0.2:8000 /mylink;
   port_in_redirect off;
}
```

Notice the `/` on the `proxy_pass` line, this causes the matched part of your `location` not to be sent to the server.

For reference, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass:

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:

Comment: This worked for me.  I didn't need the slash after the location name, that Xavier Lucas suggests.

Answer (score 3):

As your location and proxy_pass don't have a trailing slash the normalized URI won't see the `/mylink` part cut properly nor the proxy_redirect default behaviour append it. Simply use this :

```
location /mylink/ {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.2:8000/;
}
```